# How to use $excel{} in activity xml file?

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

How To use

> $excel{}

Tag in activity xml in Pace Automation Framework?

Answer (score 0):

To use **$excel{}** in activity file, User need to provide the excel path and sheet name at the flow level.

Ex:

```
<flow id="test1" name="Test1" excelPath="./data/test.xlsx" sheetName="Sheet1">

<input name="Username" value="$excel{Username}"></input>
```